# How do I save a name with my customer payment profile via ActiveMerchant::AuthorizeNetCimGateway?

Tags: ruby, authorize.net, activemerchant

The UI on Authorize.net clearly has a place for name and address information, which I can add/edit manually.

[image]

But I can't figure out how to add name information with the card

[image]

according to:

[image]

But The  [Active Merchant source file](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/a9c588f90c4c1d59f7b0f5e1dc40b9ca12cb7fbf/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/authorize_net_cim.rb#L774) doesn't seem to use anything but the card number, expiration date and card code, and the name info on the card is not sent over to Authorize.net.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for posterity this is solved, use `bill_to`:

```rb
    def create_payment_profile
      response = GatewayService.gateway.create_customer_payment_profile(
        customer_profile_id: owner.gateway_profile,
        payment_profile: {
          bill_to: bill_to,
          payment: {
            credit_card: credit_card
          }
        }
      )
    end

    def gateway_card
      ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        verification_value: cvv,
        number:             credit_card_number,
        year:               "20#{year}",
        month:              month,
      )
    end

    def bill_to
      {
        first_name:         first_name,
        last_name:          last_name,
        #company: ,
        #address1: ,
        #address: ,
        #city: ,
        #state: ,
        #zip: ,
        #country: ,
        #phone_number: ,
        #fax_number: ,
        #customer_address_id: ,
      }
    end
```